# Bower dependency for csv.js & vsv_fonts.js

Tags: bower, angular-ui-grid

For a AngularJS ui-grid feature currently I am using the below 2 dependencies directly through URL.

Are these available through 'Bower' tool please ?

```
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install `pdfmake` via bower you will find `vfs_fonts.js` in `pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js`. I know it's not exactly what you wanted but it is close.

Comment: Thanks for the help.